# < SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am playing around with the below code and do not know why it is giving me this syntax error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRf2K.png)

```
def isSupport(df,i):
    support = df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i-1]    and df['Low'][i] <
     df['Low'][i+1] and df['Low'][i+1] < df['Low'][i+2] and 
     df['Low'][i-1] < df['Low'][i-2]

     return support
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  
Off-site links and images of text are not acceptable, in keeping with this site's purpose.

Comment: Hi, as you have now answers now, you may think about [accepting an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to reward the one that gives you the most helpful comment.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentheses to also align multiline statements:

```py
support = (df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i - 1] and 
          df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i + 1] and 
          df['Low'][i + 1] < df['Low'][i + 2] and 
          df['Low'][i - 1] < df['Low'][i - 2])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

- wrap them in parenthesis

  ```
  support = (df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i - 1] and
             df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i + 1] and
             df['Low'][i + 1] < df['Low'][i + 2] and
             df['Low'][i - 1] < df['Low'][i - 2])
  ```
- put them all on same line

  ```
  support = df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i - 1] and df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i + 1] and df['Low'][i + 1] < df['Low'][i + 2] and df['Low'][i - 1] < df['Low'][i - 2]
  ```
- use `\` to signify the line-break

  ```
  support = df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i - 1] and \
            df['Low'][i] < df['Low'][i + 1] and \
            df['Low'][i + 1] < df['Low'][i + 2] and \
            df['Low'][i - 1] < df['Low'][i - 2]
  ```